# Can I create an anonymous bind using ldapjs similar to when I use php?

Tags: php, node.js, ldap

I am migrating an application from php to nodejs and I am having a problem getting access to our ldap server.

The php code uses an anonymous bind to the ldap server:

php snippet:

```
    $ds= ldap_connect("ldap.example.com");  
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT, 2);
    $r= ldap_bind($ds);read-only access
```

I am not certain of the syntax in nodejs that I would use for the anonymous bind.
My code so far is:

Nodejs snippet:

```
    var assert = require('assert');
    var ldap = require('ldapjs');
    var client = ldap.createClient({
      url: 'ldap://ldap.example.com',
      reconnect: true
    });
    console.log("after createClient");
```

// The b        ind code goes here
client.bind();

Since this is a generic ldap server to be used just to perform lookups I don't need an authenticated bind just an anonymous one, but what should go between the parentheses in the bind statement?

Answer (score 1):

According to [RFC 4513](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4513#section-5.1.1) (LDAP Authentication Methods and Security Mechanisms) :

> 5.1.1.  Anonymous Authentication Mechanism of Simple Bind
>
> An LDAP client may use the anonymous authentication mechanism of
> the simple Bind method to explicitly establish an anonymous
> authorization state by sending a Bind request with a name value of
> zero length and specifying the simple authentication choice
> containing a password value of zero length.

...this should work :

```
client.bind('', '', callback);
```